# How can I delete files or folders on github?

Tags: python, git, github, repository, delete-file

I have a python project I'm working on, and I'm keeping it on github. I recently updated it, trying to change the name of a folder. However, it actually just added the folder again without changing the other one. Is there a way I can delete the old folder? In the future, is there a better way to change the name of a file?

This is the project: https://github.com/bMacSwigg/The-Legend-of-The-Village
I replaced exe.win32-2.7 with LotV.exe-WSE, and now I want to delete exe.win32-2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you move the folder or rename it

```
git add -A
```

this will stage all changes - including deletions. Committing this, you will see that you now have a move.

In the future you can

```
mv somefile someotherfile
```

and git add -A will see this as a move.

Answer (score 1):

Adam's answer will get your project from it's current state into the correct state. For future reference, you can avoid this problem by using git to do the renaming:

```
git mv old-name new-name
```